# json decode issue on translate Json

Tags: php, json

i'm trying to convert or use a json_decode on this:

```
{
"rc": 0,
"msg": "Exitoso",
"className": "ve.com.icg.commons.to.ActivityTransfer",
"bean": "{\"memberEnrollmentList\":{\"enrolles\":    [{\"code\":\"000400\",\"companyCode\":\"18\",\"groupCode\":\"00\",\"documentId\":\"V00000232566\",\"licenseNumber\":\"00000400\",\"name\":\"BENAIM PINTO (ZL) GONZALO\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"21-APR-27\",\"maritalStatus\":\"CAS\",\"dateOfLicenseIssuance\":\"27-JUL-95\",\"dateOfLicenseExpiration\":\"30-APR-00\",\"commercialName\":\"LA ESTIC VENEZUELA\",\"codeClient\":\"00-000400\",\"gender\":\"M\",\"activitysList\":{\"activitys\":[]}},{\"code\":\"000410\",\"companyCode\":\"18\",\"groupCode\":\"11\",\"documentId\":\"V00010289740\",\"licenseNumber\":\"11000410\",\"name\":\"COHEN DE ESTRIN NANCY\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"10-MAY-70\",\"maritalStatus\":\"CAS\",\"dateOfAdmission\":\"13-DEC-02\",\"dateOfLicenseIssuance\":\"24-SEP-10\",\"dateOfLicenseExpiration\":\"30-MAY-15\",\"codeClient\":\"11-000410\",\"gender\":\"F\",\"relationshipCode\":\"E10\",\"relationship\":\"ESPOSO (A)\",\"activitysList\":{\"activitys\":[{\"code\":\"GIMNASIO-MENSUA\",\"description\":\"GIMNASIO PLAN MENSUAL\",\"sectionsList\":{\"sections\":[{\"code\":\"MENSU\",\"openings\":0,\"description\":\"GIMNASIO PLAN MENSUAL\"}]}}]}},{\"code\":\"000410\",\"companyCode\":\"18\",\"groupCode\":\"00\",\"documentId\":\"V00000960057\",\"licenseNumber\":\"00000410\",\"name\":\"ABADI DE BENAIM JUDITH\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"23-MAY-32\",\"maritalStatus\":\"VIU\",\"dateOfLicenseIssuance\":\"29-FEB-08\",\"dateOfLicenseExpiration\":\"30-MAY-13\",\"codeClient\":\"00-000410\",\"gender\":\"F\",\"relationshipCode\":\"E10\",\"relationship\":\"ESPOSO (A)\",\"activitysList\":{\"activitys\":[{\"code\":\"EVENADUL-ENSATU\",\"description\":\"ENSALADAS PARA TU BISHVAT \\\"MARISOL BENDAYAN\\\" (07/02/2012)\",\"sectionsList\":{\"sections\":[{\"code\":\"1\",\"openings\":0,\"description\":\"ENSALADAS PARA TU BISHVAT\"}]}}]}},{\"code\":\"000412\",\"companyCode\":\"18\",\"groupCode\":\"11\",\"documentId\":\"E00000786622\",\"licenseNumber\":\"11000412\",\"name\":\"SHIRLEY DOUEK DE COHEN\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-NOV-38\",\"maritalStatus\":\"CAS\",\"dateOfAdmission\":\"12-DEC-02\",\"dateOfLicenseIssuance\":\"29-JUL-07\",\"dateOfLicenseExpiration\":\"30-NOV-12\",\"codeClient\":\"11-000412\",\"gender\":\"F\",\"relationshipCode\":\"S12\",\"relationship\":\"SUEGRA\",\"activitysList\":{\"activitys\":[{\"code\":\"DEPORTES-GIMNAS\",\"description\":\"GIMNASIA ARTISTICA ESCUELAS DEPORTIVAS Y DEPORTE FEDERADO\",\"sectionsList\":{\"sections\":[{\"code\":\"GIMN10\",\"openings\":0,\"description\":\"MEJJORAMIENTO FISICO 4\"}]}}]}},{\"code\":\"000420\",\"companyCode\":\"18\",\"groupCode\":\"11\",\"licenseNumber\":\"11000420\",\"name\":\"ESTRIN COHEN SHARON\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"29-SEP-98\",\"maritalStatus\":\"SIN\",\"codeClient\":\"11-000420\",\"gender\":\"F\",\"relationshipCode\":\"H01\",\"relationship\":\"HIJO 1\",\"activitysList\":{\"activitys\":[]}},{\"code\":\"000430\",\"companyCode\":\"18\",\"groupCode\":\"11\",\"licenseNumber\":\"11000430\",\"name\":\"ESTRIN COHEN SHIRLEY\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"02-SEP-99\",\"maritalStatus\":\"SIN\",\"codeClient\":\"11-000430\",\"gender\":\"F\",\"relationshipCode\":\"H02\",\"relationship\":\"HIJO 2\",\"activitysList\":{\"activitys\":[{\"code\":\"BAILES-BADULT\",\"description\":\"BAILES ISRAELIES ADOLESCENTES\",\"sectionsList\":{\"sections\":[{\"code\":\"02\",\"openings\":0,\"description\":\"SEGUNDO AÑO\"}]}},{\"code\":\"DEPORTES-GIMNAS\",\"description\":\"GIMNASIA ARTISTICA ESCUELAS DEPORTIVAS Y DEPORTE FEDERADO\",\"sectionsList\":{\"sections\":[{\"code\":\"GIMN10\",\"openings\":0,\"description\":\"MEJJORAMIENTO FISICO 4\"}]}}]}}]}}",
"accessLog": {
    "sessionId": "0cd4ceec6d753af545d3bfc0939a0759",
    "userName": "DGAMBOA",
    "RC": 0
},
"token": "0cd4ceec6d753af545d3bfc0939a0759"
}
```

but the response its empty, how i resolve this?

I'm storage this Json in txt file and called..

```
$textJson= file_get_contents('JSON2.txt'); 
$arrJson = json_decode($textJson,true);
```

Comment: I think you should pass a json encoded string to the json_decode method, and your code doesn't seems to be correctly encoded

Comment: I agree with @Carlos487.  Also, usually adding `true` does the trick, if you have more issues:  `json_decode($json, true)`;

Comment: i think that, but i go to the page http://jsonlint.com/, and check it, the json its fine.

Comment: and, yes i'm using ($json,true), but the response it´s empty

Comment: Have your JSON been encoded using UTF-8?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking to the right result? I've run it throught json_decode and an correct array pops out. Can you pls send us the php code you are using on this.

Comment: yes kiks73, and it´s extrange because i have other json that its more complex and works fine.

Comment: i'd put the code where i'm using it, the file obviously is in the same folder that the php file

Comment: the var_dump return NULL, and before i've print $textJson, and it's return value

Comment: Its invalid json because it contains utf-8 characters, check it with `json_last_error()`

Comment: From what you posted, there is no error visible. Guess the problem lies somewhere else. http://3v4l.org/QAm6q

Comment: I think the error is in the "file_get_contents", but i've print and it show me values

Comment: @CarlosZ I guess the problem could be the `\"`. Maybe the escape sequence is not correct after the string is loaded via `file_get_contents`. Also ignore the comments regarding utf-8. It's perfectly valid to have utf-8 characters in json strings.

Comment: sorry Yoshi, i'd tried and not result

Comment: If your question has been answered, please [mark the answer that you feel best addressed your question as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), rather than posting a comment thanking the answerer. Once you have at least 15 rep, you can also [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the accepted answer and any other answers you found useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
\"description\":\"ENSALADAS PARA TU BISHVAT \\\"MARISOL BENDAYAN\\\" (07/02/2012)\"
```

Comment: Sorry, i've checked that and nothing

Comment: You are correct sir, change `\\\"MARISOL BENDAYAN\\\"` to `\"MARISOL BENDAYAN\"` or `\\\\\\"MARISOL BENDAYAN\\\\\\"` and it works as in @Yoshi example in the comments

Comment: I've solve, the error is in a "Ñ" character, i've replaced and work, the change that you suggest i'd checked before

Comment: There is no 'Ñ', even if there was, it would still parse. Glad it works though.

Comment: there is "\"openings\":0,\"description\":\"SEGUNDO AÑO\"}", but still i go to you with the +